# how to create face app in flutter using Augmented Reality

Tags: flutter, augmented-reality, face-detection

hy guys! I'm new in Augumented reality I'm developing app In flutter like this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rounz.showcase  I don't how to create app like this can someone help me please. please watch this link an guide me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop a mobile app, you can use the capabilities of facial recognition, graphics rendering, and AR display provided by Huawei AR Engine to access Product AR fitting.

AR Engine is a platform for building AR apps on Android smartphones. It integrates AR core algorithms to provide basic AR capabilities such as motion tracking, environment tracking, body tracking, and face tracking.

Huawei provides Flutter plug-ins for you to integrate AR Engine. You can download it on Github: https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-flutter-plugin/tree/master/flutter-hms-ar

The main procedures are as follows:

1. Create a **FaceViewActivity** inherited from **Activity**, and create the corresponding **layout** file.
2. Override the **onCreate** method in **FaceViewActivity** to obtain **FaceView**.
3. Create a listener for **Switch**. When Switch is enabled, call the **loadAsset** method to load the 3D model of the product. Set the position of facial recognition in **LandmarkType**.

```
mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        mFaceView.clearResource();
        if (isChecked) {
            // Load materials.
         int index = mFaceView.loadAsset("FaceView/sunglasses.glb", LandmarkType.TIP_OF_NOSE);
        }
    }
});
```

4. Create a **onBtnTryProductOn** in **MainActivity**. When the user taps the **onBtnTryProductOn** button, the **FaceViewActivity** is called, which enables the user to view the AR fitting effects.

For more details, see [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001058897997).